# Dynamically call a method based on a variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that calculates shipping costs based on the "speed" a user selects. I'm trying to refactor this if statement based on those speeds. This is the current if statement:

```
  def walk_thru_each_rate_type(speed_hash, speed_from_db)
    if speed_hash.has_key?("flex")
      handle_flex_rates(speed_from_db)
    end
    if speed_hash.has_key?("fixed")
      handle_fixed_rates(speed_from_db)
    end
    if speed_hash.has_key?("free")
      handle_free_shipping(speed_from_db)
    end
  end
```

So each method is just based on the "speed". `flex, fixed or free` and the method names have those speeds in them. I was thinking something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
handle_"#{speed}"_rates(speed_from_db)
```

How can I dynamically call my method based on the speed name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call Object#send passing the method name and the params. In your case, it would be like:

`self.send("handle_#{speed}_rates", speed_from_db)`

Take a look at https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

Comment: ahh perfect! I was confused on the object part as my methods were not in a class of their own.. I'll accept this one once I can! thanks much

Comment: [Object#pubilc_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) is recommended when sending public methods (to avoid the inadvertent sending of private methods). I don't think you need `self.`.